# Disablingselction of one item in sencha touch list

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a list with suppose 5 items and I want to disable selection and showing blue color on item tab for 1 item only and enable for others.

Is it possible to do that and how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that programmatically by adding a `itemtap` listener when you tap an item on the list. For example, you have five items and you want to disable the second item to be highlighted when selected. `Index` of the list comes into play here.

Here is the code:

```
 Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyList', {
        extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',

        config: {
            id: 'MyList',
            store: 'MyArrayStore',
            itemTpl: [
                '<div>{Value}</div>'
            ],
            listeners: [
                {
                    fn: 'onMyListItemTap',
                    event: 'itemtap'
                }
        ]
    },

    onMyListItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
        if(index===1) // 1 is the 2nd item in the list
        {
            Ext.getCmp('MyList').getAt(index).setDisabled(true); //getting the list using id 'MyList', getting the item using index and then setting it as disabled.
        }

    }

});
```